# Generic interface for conversion [keys].option.value.number to option.[Keys].number

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I'm trying to describe the following situation using generic typing and interface at typescript. 
When the function translates propertis of object created by factory from [keys].option.value.(number|string...) to option.[Keys].(number|string...)

On the last line I geting intValue instead number. Is there any magic over the Values types?

[Code on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Validator%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Value%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20validator%3A%20Validator%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20intValue%20extends%20Value%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20stringValue%20extends%20Value%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Entity%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(key%3A%20string)%3A%20intValue%20%7C%20stringValue%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Dog%20extends%20Entity%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20intValue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20intValue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20stringValue%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initObject%3CE%20extends%20Entity%3E(arg%3A%20E)%3A%20E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arg%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initInt(value%3A%20number%2C%20validator%3A%20Validator)%3A%20intValue%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20value%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20validator%3A%20validator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initString(value%3A%20string%2C%20validator%3A%20Validator)%3A%20stringValue%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20value%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20validator%3A%20validator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Values%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Valued%3CV%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20values%3A%20Values%3CV%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20validators%3A%20Values%3CV%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getValued%3CV%20extends%20Entity%3E(obj%3A%20V)%3A%20Valued%3CV%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20out%3A%20Valued%20%3C%20V%20%3E%20%3D%20%7Bvalues%3A%5B%5D%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20in%20obj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20o%3AintValue%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out.values%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20o.value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out.validators%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20o.validator%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20out%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20objectDog%20%3D%20initObject(%3CDog%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20initInt(1%2C%20%7B%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20initInt(12%2C%20%7B%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20initString(%22Nuf%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20valuedDog%20%3D%20getValued(objectDog)%3B%0D%0AvaluedDog.values.id%3B%20%2F%2F%20There%20id%20is%20type%20intValue%20i%20want%20get%20number%20type%20here%0D%0A%0D%0A)

```
interface Validator { }

interface Value<T> { 
    value: T
    validator: Validator
}

interface intValue extends Value<number> {}
interface stringValue extends Value<string> {}

interface Entity {
    (key: string): intValue | stringValue
}

interface Dog extends Entity {
    id: intValue;
    age: intValue;
    name: stringValue;
} 

function initObject<E extends Entity>(arg: E): E {
    return arg;
}

function initInt(value: number, validator: Validator): intValue {
    return {
        value: value,
        validator: validator
    }
}

function initString(value: string, validator: Validator): stringValue {
    return {
        value: value,
        validator: validator
    }
}

type Values<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}

interface Valued<V> {
    values: Values<V>;
    validators: Values<V>;
}

function getValued<V extends Entity>(obj: V): Valued<V>{
    let out: Valued < V > = {values:[]};

    for (let key in obj) {
        const o:intValue = obj[key];
        out.values[key] = o.value;
        out.validators[key] = o.validator;
    }

    return out;
}

const objectDog = initObject(<Dog>{
    id: initInt(1, {}),
    age: initInt(12, {}),
    name: initString("Nuf", {})
})

const valuedDog = getValued(objectDog);
valuedDog.values.id; // There id is type intValue i want get number type here
```

Thanks, for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't spend the time going through all your code, but it *looks* like you want the definition of `Values<>` to be like this:

```
type Values<V extends Entity> = {
  [P in keyof V]?: V[P]['value'];
}
```

That is, the `Values<V>` type should "unwrap" the property values in `V`.  Then you only need to change `Valued<V>` to `Valued<V extends Entity>`:

```
interface Valued<V extends Entity> {
  values: Values<V>;
  validators: Values<V>;
}
```

And then your code type-checks and returns more or less what you said you wanted (well, it's `number | undefined` since `Values<>` properties are optional... remove the `?` if you don't want that).  Not sure if the code behaves as you want, but you're probably the best judge of that.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, you are genius, it is exactly what i looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I got the following code to work as you describe.  I assume the changes are acceptable.  If not, please describe why and I'll take a second look.

```
interface Validator { }

interface Value<T> { 
    value: T
    validator: Validator
}

interface intValue extends Value<number> {}
interface stringValue extends Value<string> {}

interface Entity {
    (key: string): intValue | stringValue
}

interface Dog extends Entity {
    id: intValue;
    age: intValue;
    name: stringValue;
} 

function initObject<E extends Entity>(arg: E): E {
    return arg;
}

function initInt(value: number, validator: Validator): intValue {
    return {
        value: value,
        validator: validator
    }
}

function initString(value: string, validator: Validator): stringValue {
    return {
        value: value,
        validator: validator
    }
}

type Values<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}

interface Valued<V> {
    values: Values<V>;
    validators: Values<V>;
}

function getValued<V extends Entity>(obj: V): Valued<V>{
    // initialize to empty object not array and initialize validators
    let out: Valued<V> = { values: {}, validators: {} }; 

    // const instead of let
    for (const key in obj) {
        const o:intValue = obj[key];
        out.values[key] = o.value;
        out.validators[key] = o.validator;
    }

    return out;
}

const objectDog = initObject(<Dog>{
    id: initInt(1, {}),
    age: initInt(12, {}),
    name: initString("Nuf", {})
}); // semicolon

const valuedDog = getValued(objectDog);

// Added .value here
valuedDog.values.id.value;
```

P.S. I hope there is a *really* good reason for this style of abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for help, 

but it is exactly what i dont want.

I am trying describe that in valuedDog.values.id i will get 1, for valuedDog.values.age 
 = 12..

Is there way how i can at typescript describe: **If properties has stringValue, then same property of object returned by any function will be string..**

Its for situation when i want describe any object and its properties with default values, validation rules, values, erorrs, etc..

And then get only default values..

Comment: @TomášBurda I understand now - @jcalz answer (as you have already discovered) is precisely what you want then.  The missing `.value` in the example code threw me off track.